# Define mono for only one VirtualHost

Tags: apache, mono, virtualhost

I am running an Apache Server with multiple VirtualHosts, and of course I know how to create a new VirtualHost, but I do not know, how I can setup Mono only for this VirtualHost.

I have read I need to disable MonoAutoApplication, but I can not find any information on how to set it up on only this VirtualHost.

Can anybody in here help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mono project hosts a web-based wizard for generating mod_mono configurations for Apache.  You can find the tool online here:
http://www.go-mono.com/config-mod-mono/

The default is to create a configuration file for a new Virtual Host.